# swf as trusted in android webview

Tags: android, webview, flash, trusted

I am try to load a SWF file in webview android, my SWF load other files locally and acces to network,
i test it in a web browser in computer, will set the SWF as trusted from **Global Security Settings panel**:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

but in android it load other page, it contains only local storage and peer-Assisted networking:

http://settings.adobe.com/flashplayer/mobile/

is there any way to configure my SWF as trusted?

or is there another way for my SWF can read files locally and access to network?

Answer (score 0):

Flash is not supported on modern Android versions. Chrome for Android (on which modern Android WebView is based) just never ever supported Flash.

Comment: i´m install flash player 11 for andriod 4.0 from page: [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#main_Archived_versions)